# The equivalent of esc-delete in zsh

Tags: command-line, zsh

In bash, the emacs key sequence \e^? (escape-delete) deletes a single word. that is, if you have a command line like

```
ls /a/b/c
```

with the cursor after the 'c', and you want to delete that 'c', you press \e^?. You'll be left with

```
ls /a/b/
```

That key sequence in zsh deletes the '/a/b/c'.

when I do

```
bindkey
```

and search for 'word', I get

```
^W backward-kill-word.
```

If I do that with my example, it deletes the '/a/b/c'.

so, what constitutes a 'word' in zsh is different from what's a 'word' in bash. I like bash's definition. How do I change zsh to use bash's definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the `WORDCHARS` parameter defines which non-alphanumeric characters are considered part of a word. By default, it includes `/`:

```
% echo $WORDCHARS
*?_-.[]~=/&;!#$%^(){}<>
```

You can redefine this; for example, to remove `/`:

```
% WORDCHARS=${WORDCHARS/\//}
```

(If I remember correctly, `bash` doesn't include *any* non-alphanumeric characters in its--or more precisely, Readline's--defintion of a word, and you cannot modify that. If that's true, then setting `WORDCHARS` to the empty string would most closely change `zsh` to behave like `bash`.)

Comment: Perfect! Exactly as desired. 

What is 'WORDCHARS?' It isn't an environmental variable. It's mentioned only once at https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/zsh_a4.pdf but never actually defined.

Comment: It's just an ordinary shell parameter that the shell itself initializes to the value shown on the answer.

Comment: (I should say, it's a *special* shell parameter, but that just means one whose value the shell itself uses, rather than being one you are free to use for your own purposes.)